# addMarkers pop up not correct r leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, marker

Trying to `print` info in the `popup` menu of `addMarkers()` in `r leaflet` 
package

here is my data frame:

```
quakes%>%
        filter(mag>5.5)%>%
        arrange(stations)
```

it correctly puts the pin in the right lat long location.

for the popup this is what i have tried:

```
quakes%>%
    filter(mag>5.5)%>%
    arrange(stations)%>%
    leaflet()%>%
    addTiles()%>%
    addMarkers(popup=paste("Latitude:", quakes$lat, "<br>", 
                     "Longitude:", quakes$long, "<br>",
                     "Station:",quakes$stations,"<br>",
                     "Megnitude:", quakes$mag))
```

the popups clearly have values below the `filter`
what am i missing?

Comment: this is more a question regarding piping I guess... You're querying `quakes$mag` in your popup call, which, if I am not mistaken is still the original dataframe not the filtered one. Try splitting your pipe in several steps, i.e. first filter and save to a new object, then plot.

Comment: @TimSalabim it works fine in that regard. I was looking for a solution where I don't need to save the results in to a new dataframe. thanks for your reply any way